# IPython dir '/home/vision/.ipython' is not a writable location, using a temp directory. warn("IPython dir '{0}' is not a writable location,"

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I installed jupyter notebook using pip. Now when i try to open jupyter notebook using the command jupyter notebook in terminal, it shows the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/paths.py:63: UserWarning: IPython dir '/home/vision/.ipython' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
  warn("IPython dir '{0}' is not a writable location,"
[C 14:37:21.376 NotebookApp] Running as root is not recommended. Use --allow-root to bypass.
```

Please help me to use jupyter notebook in my laptop.